# BigQuery: getTables doesn't return table names (Node.js )

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I'm having issues getting table names from a dataset using getTables (Node.js).  I have read / write access to the tables in the dataset and the function does return some information so it should not be an auth issue.

I referred to [the GAPI documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/Dataset#getTables) and tried the following:

```
const BigQuery = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");
const bigquery = new BigQuery([Project ID]);
const datasetId = [dataset ID];

bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .getTables(function(err, tables){
        console.log(tables);
});
```

and the result looks like this:

```
[ Table {
    bigQuery: BigQuery { location: undefined },
    dataset: Dataset { bigQuery: [Object] } },
  Table {
    bigQuery: BigQuery { location: undefined },
    dataset: Dataset { bigQuery: [Object] } },
  Table {
    bigQuery: BigQuery { location: undefined },
    dataset: Dataset { bigQuery: [Object] } },
  Table {
    bigQuery: BigQuery { location: undefined },
    dataset: Dataset { bigQuery: [Object] } } ]
```

I have four tables in the dataset so the number of rows is correct, but it provides no details on each of the tables. Also `console.log(tables[0]);` returns this:

```
Table {
  bigQuery: BigQuery { location: undefined },
  dataset: Dataset { bigQuery: BigQuery { location: undefined } } }
```

...which is quite different from [what I expect it to return](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/list).

I tried passing the location code in the `options` object, but it didn't make much difference. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Upon searching I was able to find this public [reference](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/b0b9605ea6df8940477d8f4c14092012ab1e7d2f/samples/tables.js#L88) which I've tested and it listed all the tables within my dataset using getTables(). Here how my code looks like:

```
function listTables(datasetId, projectId) {
  const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

  const bigquery = new BigQuery({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

  // Lists all tables in the dataset
  bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .getTables()
    .then(results => {
      const tables = results[0];
      console.log('Tables:');
      tables.forEach(table => console.log(table.id));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
  // [END bigquery_list_tables]
}

listTables('YOUR_DATASET_NAME','YOUR_PROJECT_NAME');
```

Comment: The example worked. Looks like `tables.forEach(table => console.log(table.id));` was what I was missing. Thank you so much Steeve

Comment: @mori-sugimoro You could have accepted the answer :)